# Display a chart in PartialVIew on layout not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I am trying to display a chart on my layout. The chart is inside a partialview. But I get this error:::

> Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the
>   InnerException for more information
>
> The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement
>   IController.

new error: {"Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."}

This is my OfficeStatisticNKIcontroller : Controller

```
public ActionResult Partialchart()
        {
            OfficeStatisticQueryViewModel model = new OfficeStatisticQueryViewModel();
            model.StartDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            model.EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            int allcompletedNKI = OfficeStatisticRepository.AllCompletedGoalCards();
            model.AllCompletedNKI = allcompletedNKI;
            var averageGrades = OfficeStatisticRepository.GetAverageGradeForAllCoreValues2();
            if (averageGrades.Count != 0)
            {
                var dataItems = (averageGrades.Select(averageGrade => averageGrade.AverageGrade).ToArray());
                Data data = new Data(
                    dataItems.Select(y => new Point { Color = GetBarColour(y), Y = y }).ToArray());

                Highcharts chart1 = new Highcharts("Chart")
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = averageGrades.Select(averageGrade => averageGrade.CoreValue.Name).ToArray() })
                .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Min = 0, Max = 10, TickInterval = 1, Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Betygskalan" } })
                .SetSeries(new Series { Data = data, Name = "Snittbetyg" })
                .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
                .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "statistic" })
                .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column });

                model.Chart = chart1;
                model.message = " ";
                return PartialView(model);
            }
            else
            {
                model.message = "error";
                return PartialView(model);
            }

        }
```

and this is my code in my layout:

```
@Html.Action("Partialchart","OfficeStatisticNKI");
```

All I want to do is to display this chart what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what does the inner-exception say?

Comment: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Answer (score 0):

The action method you've displayed here are you sure it is contained within the **OfficeStatisticNKI** controller? Does your controller inherit from the **Controller** class?

Comment: I have my actionmethod inside this  public class OfficeStatisticNKIController : Controller
    {} still not working

Comment: I recieve now {"Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."}